# Movie title mystery - something about pandora's box?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I have been trying to figure out the name of a movie that came out sometime between the early 90's to mid 2000's. I distinctly remember there being a small pandora's box type cube.  I think it was found in an archaeological dig site and may have even been on another planet or involved aliens. Obviously something bad happened afterwards.  I'm not sure that I even ever saw the movie. I definitely remember seeing the preview and the narrator mentioning something about bad things happening because they unknowingly opened pandora's box. I realize this is a vague description and I may have some details wrong because my memory from this period of time is damaged.

Comment: Tomb Raider- Cradle of Life? :)

Comment: [Ghosts of Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_of_Mars) fits a number of your criteria, but not all. From 2001, set on Mars, involves aliens, a dig site, and it's described as "pandora's box",  but it's not a small box.

Comment: Maybe the Hellraiser franchise, particularly Hellraiser: Bloodline.

Comment: Any additional details would help - as-is, this is a hugely broad parameter set.

Comment: Its not tomb raider or ghosts of mars. The main thing I remember is the typical 90's deep "end of the world" narrator voice saying they did not realize that they had opened pandora's box and all hell will break loose. then it shows like aliens or demons or something breaking out and it cuts to blackness. There may or may not have been ancient weapons - swords,etc. involved. Thank you for trying to help me. I got knocked around from IED's in Iraq and cannot remember very much before 2006. For some reason I remembered this preview and I am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, this may have been the full trailer for [Alone in the Dark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alone_in_the_Dark_(2005_film)) (2005), starring Christian Slater and Tara Reid. The movie was universally panned, but honestly it wasn't THAT bad in my opinon.

The film has almost no connection to the game series of the same name, but instead revolves around the accidental opening of a portal which allows demonic shadow-like creatures onto Earth from another dimension. I am unable to find the full trailer while at work, but will try to get it added this evening.

The movie involves much of what you described, with numerous scenes taking place in a museum and ancient artifacts being central to the plot. The demonic creatures of the film look very similar in design to the [Xenomorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)) of the Alien franchise, and one of the ancient artifacts is cube-like in shape (actually, it's more like a hexagon I think). At one point during the film, the protagonists are fighting one of the demons while in the museum or its warehouse, and use whatever they can - including ancient weapons - to fend off the creature.

**UPDATE:** I was unable to find the full trailer on YouTube, but it turned out I had a copy of it from way back in 2005 when the movie originally came out (and my wife says my hoarding isn't good for anything... HA). I uploaded the trailer to YouTube and here it is:

***Narration Guy:***  Some gateways... should never be opened. Some fears... should never be seen. And some terrors... can never be stopped.

Comment: Your video has been blocked already. Here's a valid video link: http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi4088725785/

Comment: @CreationEdge thanks. That's just insane - what movie studio would NOT want its film trailers available to the public? Especially one that's 10 years old. Sure enough, though, I checked and it was blocked by a copyright violation from Lionsgate Entertainment.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of [Hellraiser IV: Bloodline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellraiser:_Bloodline)?

It involves the Lament Configuration (a small cube); the Cenobites (demons which could be mistaken for alien); part of it takes place on a space station; and it's Hellraiser so it's very gloom-and-doom.